# enviar correo electrónico desde java

Tags: java, jsp

lo que me pasa es que ejecuto el programa y cuando le doy enviar me dice mensaje no enviado pero no se por que no me deja enviar el correo (ya configure el correo para que pueda enviar mensajes desde orígenes desconocidos ) espero puedan ayudarme

este es mi index.jsp

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>FORMULARIO PARA ENVIAR CORREO ELECTRONICO - TUTORIAL 10 JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h2>FORMULARIO ENVIO CORREO ELECTRONICO</h2>
        
        <form action="resultado.jsp" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>PARA: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="para" id="para"/></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>ASUNTO: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>MENSAJE: </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="mensaje" cols="40" rows="10" id="mensaje"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="ENVIAR CORREO ELECTRONICO"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

esta es la clase mensaje

```html
package modelo;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author Seba
 */
public class Email {
 //public boolean enviarCorreo(String de, String clave, String[] para, String mensaje, String asunto){
  public boolean enviarCorreo( String para, String mensaje, String asunto){
        boolean enviado = false;
            try{
            
                String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                String de = "luisasuazam@gmail.com";
                String clave ="***";
                
                Properties prop = System.getProperties();
                
                prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                prop.put("mail.smtp.user",de);
                prop.put("mail.smtp.password", clave);
                prop.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
                prop.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
                
                Session sesion = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop,null);
                
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sesion);
                
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(de));
                
               /*
                    
                    NOTA: para enviar correo electronico masivo
                
                    InternetAddress[] direcciones = new InternetAddress[para.length];
                    for(int i=0;i<para.length;i++){
                        direcciones[i] = new InternetAddress(para[i]);
                    }
                
                    for(int i=0;i<direcciones.length;i++){
                        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, direcciones[i]);
                    }
                
               */
                
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(para));
                
                message.setSubject(asunto);
                message.setText(mensaje);
                
                Transport transport = sesion.getTransport("smtp");
                
                transport.connect(host,de,clave);
                
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                
                transport.close();
                
                enviado = true;
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        return enviado;
    }
     
     
}
```

esta es la clase resultado.js

```html
<%@page import="modelo.Email"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>RESULTADO CORREO ELECTRONICO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <%
            
            Email email = new Email();
            
          
            String para = request.getParameter("para");
            String mensaje = request.getParameter("mensaje");
            String asunto = request.getParameter("asunto");
            
            /* 
                
                String[] direcciones = {"correo numero 1","correo numero 2","correo numero 3","correo ..."}
                boolean resultado = email.enviarCorreo(de, clave, direcciones, mensaje, asunto);
            
            */
            
            boolean resultado = email.enviarCorreo(para, mensaje, asunto);
            
            if(resultado){
                out.print("CORREO ELECTRONICO CORRECTAMENTE ENVIADO....."+"\n\n"+"<a href='index.jsp'>VOLVER AL INDEX</a>");
            }else{
                out.print("CORREO ELECTRONICO NO ENVIADO....."+"\n\n"+"<a href='index.jsp'>VOLVER AL INDEX</a>"); 
            }
            
        %>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

error

```html
20-Sep-2018 13:39:57.832 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\luisa\Downloads\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.4\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [265] ms
20-Sep-2018 13:39:57.843 INFORMACIÓN [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2016"]
20-Sep-2018 13:39:57.863 INFORMACIÓN [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Sep-2018 13:39:57.868 INFORMACIÓN [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 11361 ms
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to convert connection to SSL (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection.getConnectedTLSSocket(MailConnection.java:609)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.getConnectedTLSSocket(SMTPConnection.java:861)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.sendHandshake(SMTPConnection.java:822)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.protocolConnect(SMTPConnection.java:154)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:165)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:251)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:91)
 at modelo.Email.enviarCorreo(Email.java:67)
 at org.apache.jsp.resultado_jsp._jspService(resultado_jsp.java:140)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
 at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection.getConnectedTLSSocket(MailConnection.java:599)
 ... 41 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
 at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)
 at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection$SSLTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(MailConnection.java:947)
 at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:985)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
 ... 49 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
 at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
 at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
 ... 57 more
```

Comment: si no se envía, se debe estar generando una traza de error. añadela al post, por favor

Comment: Añade la excepcion que te arroja al ejecutar, eso seria de mucha ayuda para ayudarte a resolver tu inconveniente

Answer (score 1):

Puede intentar comentar la siguiente linea:

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

Es probable que la librería no pueda establecer una conexión segura.